# How can I manually modify the Http cache?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Imagine 2 apis: `/api/customer/{customer_id}` and `/api/order/{order_id}`. The first gives a bunch of customer data including an array of recent order objects. The latter just retrieves a single order object. If my front end app calls `/api/customer/bob_marley`, it maybe gets back:

```
{
  name: 'bob',
  orders: [{
    id: 'guitar'
    price: 100
  }]
}
```

Since I retrieved this with a default `fetch()` operation, it should go into my Http Cache with some expiration. But I know that the user may go to a page to view an order, and I already know what that order will return.

What I want to do is something like

```
const resp = await fetch(`/api/customer/bob_marley`)
const json = await resp.json()
json.orders.forEach(o => {
  HttpCache.add('/api/order/${o.id}', o)
})
```

such that any subsequent calls to `/api/order/guitar` will return the result I already know it will be. Can I do this? I've done my requisite googling, but all the articles I find related to Http caches just describe how to modify the behavior in `fetch`.

Comment: A ServiceWorker can do this and other shenanigans.

Comment: "*just describe how to modify the behavior of fetch*" - but isn't that basically what a http cache does? What articles exactly did you find and found not suitable?

Comment: *ServiceWorker* seems interesting, though it sounds a bit more complicated than what I described. It's not the question though, as I specifically am asking about modifying the browser Http cache, rather than "how can I achieve a similar effect to..."

Comment: Yes, service workers are rather complicated, but they offer all the flexibility to solve this quite specific -  and many other! - use cases. No, there is no simple `HttpCache` api that you're imagining.

Comment: If the answer is simply "there is no way to manually alter the Http cache from browser (but here's an idea for an alternative)", I'm happy to accept that, and maybe it will help someone in the future.

Comment: Indeed - it is.

Comment: Can't you just `fetch` /api/order/{order_id} and discard the result?